# When and how are Binding of Isaac floors generated?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

I guess it's based on random number generator, but when does the engine generate new floors? Just before entering the trapdoor, during the animation or during the cutscene? Or maybe are all floors generated at the beginning? Same thing goes for items in item rooms and shops. Are they based on frame number, RNG, or preset during level generation?

Comment: I'm curious just what use you're intending to put the answer to - or is it just pure curiosity?

Comment: I want to use program named Hourglass to do a Tool-assisted run, manipulate luck, ram-search for boss/item/shop positions to minimize walking around and do other stuff like that.

Comment: This seems like a more suitable question for the [Game Dev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange rather than here.

Comment: @Mana I have to disagree _somewhat_. While this question does carry a certain odor of stale cheetos and neckbeards, I'm not sure it's technical enough for gamedev. I think this is a case of there being some overlap between here and gamedev, and since the question's not quite of either exchange's perview we should probably let it stand.

Answer (score 7):

> "rooms are generated when you start a level, but the random aspects of each room are generated when you go inside the room. also the drops that come from killing enemies and rocks are generated when you kill said enemies/rocks"

-From Edmund Mcmillen's [Formspring](http://www.formspring.me/EdmundM/q/295098806947549598).